# Problems importing org.eclipse modules into pydev project

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Im trying to make a script than needs org.eclipse modules like:

org.eclipse.jface.dialogs
org.eclipse.core.resources

but when I run the script Eclipse told me that such modules doesnt exist, where I can find them or what can I do to make it work.

Im using eclipse 3.5.1 and Fedora 12

Thanks in advance